# PayPal IPN: custom field not passing to IPN

Tags: paypal-ipn

I have a paypal buy button that looks like this:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> 

<input type="hidden" name="business" value="my@email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="item1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="item2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="5">

<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="Admin|2">
<input type="hidden" name="discount_rate_cart" value="5">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="paypal-ipn.php">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR"> 
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="Thank-you-page">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="SE">

<input type="submit" value="Checkout" id="checkoutButton">
</form>
```

And a IPN that looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

// STEP 1: read POST data

// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();

foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval)
{
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
    {
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }
}

// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc'))
{
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value)
{        
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1)
    { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
    }
    else
    {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }

    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// Step 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set 
// the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) )
{
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}

curl_close($ch);

if(strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
{
    // The IPN is verified, process it:
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process the notification

    // assign posted variables to local variables


    $custom = explode('|', $_POST['custom']);
    $user = $custom['0'];
    $itemAmount = $custom['1'];

    $item_name = "";

    for($i = 0 ; $i < $itemAmount ; $i++)
    {
        $item_name .= $_POST['item_name_' . ($i + 1)] . '<br>';
    }

    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'] . ' ' . $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $accstatus = $_POST['payer_status'];

    include("../config.php");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `purchase` (`product`,`member`,`amount`,`ppmail`,`accstatus`,`status`)
    VALUES
    ('$item_name','$user','$payment_amount','$payer_email','$accstatus','$payment_status')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $post_data_string = serialize($_POST);
    mail('mail@domain.com', 'PayPal IPN', $post_data_string);

    mysql_close($con);

    // IPN message values depend upon the type of notification sent.
    // To loop through the &_POST array and print the NV pairs to the screen:
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key." = ". $value."<br>";
    }
}
else if(strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0)
{
    // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
    echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";
}
?>
```

Now why does not the custom field get passed on to the API?

I do get this in error logging, because custom[0] = "" and custom[1] does not exist:

```
HP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home1/planetzi/public_html/firefallcrystite/action/paypal-ipn.php on line 79
```

Comment: It works for me. I suggest you have a look at the actual value of `$_POST['custom'].`

Comment: inspecting source tells me the custom field has value="Admin|2" and the mail() part tells me that "custom";s:0:""; so it seem empty.

Comment: I didn't say anything about inspecting source. I don't know what the 'mail()' part means: there isn't one in your question. What did you find when you looked at what I suggested you look at?